# JS/jQuery Prototyping Issue, possible scoping concerns

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks for reading. I have a jQuery function I would like to prototype. The function simply binds a hide/show function to a checkbox. Each checkbox corresponds to different element to be hidden. I've been console logging, and the objects are being created; no other errors on thrown on console. This function works:

```
$("input[name='fcrBox']").bind('change', function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#result").show();
    } else {
        $("#result").hide();
    }
});
```

but this does not:

```
function HideShow(elem, affected) {
this.elem = elem;
this.affected = affected;
}

var fcrBox = new HideShow('input[name="fcrBox"]', '#result');
var sc = new HideShow('input[name="sc"]', '#MQSresult');

console.log(fcrBox);
console.log(sc);

HideShow.prototype.binder = function(elem, affected){
    $(elem).bind('change', function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked')){
            $(affected).show();
        } else {
        $(affected).hide();
        }
    });
}

fcrBox.binder();
sc.binder();
```

Thanks! Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `binder` with two parameters (`elem` and `affected`), but you don't pass any values when you call the method.

If you want to access the values that you have passed to the constructor and assigned to the object, you have to access those *explicitly*. Those values are not magically passed to `binder`.

```
function HideShow(elem, affected) {
    this.elem = elem; // <-----------------------------------------------|
    this.affected = affected;                                         // |
}                                                                     // |
                                                                      // |
var fcrBox = new HideShow('input[name="fcrBox"]', '#result');         // |
var sc = new HideShow('input[name="sc"]', '#MQSresult');              // |
                                                                      // |
console.log(fcrBox);                                                  // |
console.log(sc);                                                      // |
                                                                      // |
HideShow.prototype.binder = function(){                               // |
    var self = this; // reference to the instance; this is the same as --|
    $(self.elem).bind('change', function(){
        // In the event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element, not the
        // `HideShow` instance. But we can access the instance via `self`.
        if( $(this).is(':checked')){ // shorter: this.checked
            $(self.affected).show();
        } else {
            $(self.affected).hide();
        }
    });
}

fcrBox.binder();
sc.binder();
```